# DNS Issues connection with AT&

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, cloudflare

I run a new website called Yclas.com. I am bootstrapping the business and finally got the first paid customers but I am stuck with an issue with 2 customers from USA.

This 2 customers use AT&T as internet provider for their phones. They can not access this sites:

Example, can not access:

- http://cars.yclas.com/
  This sites go to IP: 91.121.25.98.

Message they receive:
"Google Chrome could not load the webpage because jobs.yclas.com took too long to respond. The website may be down, or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection."

Happens same in firefox.

But they can access if they turn their wireless and they connect via verizon for example. So doesn't seem a device error.

Gets more strange since they can access with AT&T to:

- http://content.yclas.com/

This ones go to ip 104.28.30.23 different IP since we use cloudflare between.

For customer at merctrader.yclas.com had same issue, I added the subdomain manually on clodflrare and now its working to him.

All this sites are hosting in the same server :S

I have run many network tests and all of them worked properly. Quite desperate here, any help would be super appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Seems an issue from AT&T, read more here:
https://yclas.com/blog/connectivity-issues-with-att.html

Comment: Where do you get the 404? link seems to be working.

Comment: OK, now it loads. You really should post the relevant parts of the answer here, though, as external sites do tend to die.